# Как работает эта магия c new Date?

Tags: javascript

```
  // Определим текущий месяц и год
  var month = parseInt(new Date().getMonth());
  var year = new Date().getFullYear();

  // Определим количество дней в месяце
  var total_days = 32 - new Date(year, month, 32).getDate();
  console.log(total_days);
```

Работает правильно, но что происходит? Как работает строчка где `var total_days =` вообще не понимаю, узнать дату на 32-й день?

Comment: когда используешь число дней больше, чем дней в месяце он перепрыгивает на следующий месяц,  соответственно если в месяце 30 дней new Date(year, month, 32).getDate(); вернет - 2, если 31 - 1 итд.  И чтобы узнать сколько дней в текущем месяце просто вычитается из 32

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Работа магии основана на том что если в конструктор даты передать количество дней больше чем в текущем месяце, то дата автоматически промотается в следующий месяц.

То есть

```
new Date(2017, 7, 33)
```

Вернет не 33 августа а второе сентября.

`getDate()` [вернет порядковый номер дня в месяце соответственно](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate). То есть 2 - для второго сентября, 1 - для первого.

Соответственно передав 32 в конструктор даты для месяца с 30 днями - мы придем на второе число, для месяца с 31 днями - на первое. С 28 днями - на четвертое. Это число и вычитаем.

Соответственно эта магия завязана на неочевидное (хоть и описанное в спецификации) свойство конструктора даты, и я рекомендовал бы такое щедро комментировать.

Comment: C плюсованием дней ладно, а вот когда в не високосный год из 31 марта отнимаешь месяц - вот тут самое веселье начинается))

Answer (score 2):

Полагаю, что Date(year, month, 32) создаёт дату в следующем месяце. Если в этом месяце было 30 дней, то 32 дня от начала текущего месяца - это 2 число следующего. Если в месяце 31 день - это 1 число. Соответственно, getDate() возвращает текущий день, при вычитании из 32 получаем 30 или 31 день в этом месяце.

Answer (score 1):

`Date` принимает 3 параметра - год, месяц и день месяца.
Передать день месяца больший чем есть в указанном месяце то Date автоматически добавит новый месяц (как если бы передавалось количество дней с начала месяца).

Тоесть к примеру
2017-01-32 - будет 2017-02-01
а 
2017-02-32 - будет 2017-03-04

Comment: Date принимает 7 параметров :-)

Answer (score 0):

Создавая нулевую дату следующего месяца Js возьмет последнюю дату Вашего месяца что и будет показывать количество дней) Всем чистого кода

```
const today = new Date();

const lastDay = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();

console.log(lastDay);
```